# Regex matching left single quotation outside the double quotations

Tags: c#, .net, regex, lookbehind

Note :

left double quotation (") = &ldquo

right double quotation (") = &rdquo

left single quotation (') = &lsquo

My current regex is this

```
(?<!.*&ldquo.*)&lsquo
```

It matches the &lsquo in here (which is right):

```
&ldquoThis is a sample&rdquo &lsquosample text
```

It also matches the &lsquo in here (which I don't want to happen because the single quote is inside the left and right double quote):

```
&ldquoThis &lsquois a sample&rdquo
```

How can I write a regex that will match every &lsquo that are NOT inside the left and right quotation

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: what about the `right single quote`.Is it there or not..Plz explain properly about what you actually want!With a list of **VALID** and **INVALID** examples...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here but I get a feeling that you are trying to parse a non regular expression. What happens if the quotes are nested and then nested again?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood ur question..This may be what you want

```
(?<!&ldquo.*?)&lsquo(?!&rdquo)
```

Comment: I need to match all &lsquo that are outside of &ldquo and &rdquo,

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With that I found my right regex for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASCII escape sequence to tell the regex which characters are you referring to.

- `\x93` - Refers to &ldquo
- `\x94` - Refers to &rdquo

So the regex you need is: `[\x93]*[^x94]`

Or if your you know what characters your string consists of, then: `[A-Za-z0-9\x93]*[^x94]`, and so on. Add more characters as per your need.

Comment: no, I need to match &lsquo that are not inside of &ldquo and &rdquo, for example, &lsquosample&rsquo &ldquosample text&rdquo.

Answer (score 0):

this is the right regex that I am looking at :

```
(?<!.*&ldquo;)&lsquo;(?!.*&rdquo;)
```

Thanks!