# Regex using Negative lookbehind and Negative lookahead assertion

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex matching left single quotation outside the double quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103448/regex-matching-left-single-quotation-outside-the-double-quotations)

First Note:

```
&ldquo - left double quote (")
&rdquo - right double quote (")
&lsquo - left single quote (')
&rsquo - right single quote (')
```

I need to match all "Left single quote" that are not inside of left and right double quote.

For clarricifcation:

1. This is a `&ldquo;sample &lsquo string &rsquo &rdquo`   -> this should not be match because the `&lsquo` (single quotes) is inside the double quote
2. This is a `&lsquo sample &rsquo`   -> the &lsquo should be match because that is not inside the double quotation

Here's my current regex:

```
(?<!.*&ldquo)&lsquo(?!.*&rdquo)
```

The problem with this is, it is looking both the `&ldquo` and `&rdquo`, if any of ldquo and rdquo occure, it will not match

for example:

1. This is a `&lsquo sample &rdquo`   -> I need to match &lsquo here but because of the appearance of &rdquo, the regex didn't match
2. This is `&ldquo a string &lsquo sample` -> same problem with no.1 example

Hope somebody can help me! thanks!

Comment: "Inside" quotes is different from "there is a double quote following". I assume you do want to match `&lsquo` in `&lsquo &ldquo &rdquo`. Also, shouldn't there be semicolons after the entity names?

Comment: this is the second time you are asking this

Comment: yes, because I still didn't fix it. :(

Comment: Then why did you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but try this

```
(?<!&ldquo.*)&lsquo(?!.*&rdquo)
```